# ngnix location directive not working

Tags: node.js, http, nginx

I have a below sample url format

> http://test.example.com:3000/samp/value?AP=API&SE=AU

where value is dynamic

Below is my ngnix config file

```
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
# HTTPS server                                                                            

upstream node_entry {
server test.example.com:3000
}                                                                               
server {
listen       443;   
ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/myssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/myssl.key;
server_name  domainname;
location / {
    #root   html;
    #index  index.html index.htm;
    return 503;
}
location /samp {
    proxy_pass   node_entry;
}
}

}
```

> When I hit 
>   http://test.example.com/samp/value?AP=API&SE=AU I get an error saying Cannot get
>
> /samp/value?AP=API&SE=AU. 
>   What Im doing wrong here.

Any help on this will be really helpful

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
proxy_pass   node_entry;
```

to

```
proxy_pass   https://node_entry;
```

For configuration tests you can run `nginx -t` and get some like

```
nginx: the configuration file conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file conf/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Or

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in conf/nginx.conf:26
nginx: configuration file conf/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: When i hit in url https://test.example.com:3000/samp/value?AP=API&SE=AU i get error "The web page is not available"